# Ring of locally finite matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be a countable set. A matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j \in I}$ is locally finite if for every $i \in I$, the families $(a_{ij})_{j\in I}$ and $(a_{ji})_{j\in I}$ have finite support . Denote by $M_{I}(\mathbb{Z})$ the ring of locally finite matrices with integral entries indexed by $I \times I$. My question is, how is this ring defined  if $|I|= \infty$? I guess addition is just the *usual* matrix addition but what about the multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual: $(A.B)_{ij}=\displaystyle\sum_{k\in I} a_{ik}b_{kj}$. Since $A$ has finite support for each $i\in I$,  $a_{ik}=0$ except for a finite number of indices $k$, so the sum is finite.

Comment: I see, I was over-complicating it. Thanks for your help!